# Dockerized FastAPI SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi

This is a sudden error, whose root cause I haven't been able to figure out.
I successfully built 2 Docker images that are connected over the same network:

1. FastAPI
2. PostgreSQL

I am not able to use the SQLAlchemy dependency injection to connect to my DB.
However, I was able to seed my DB successfully many times over.
Only made one additional field addition to my SQLAlchemy model and then this failure occurred.

```
backend-web-1  | ERROR:services.utils:Health check failed in 0.00 seconds: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
backend-web-1  | ERROR:services.utils:Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-web-1  |   File "/app/main.py", line 27, in read_root
backend-web-1  |     db.execute('SELECT 1')
backend-web-1  |     ^^^^^^^^^^
backend-web-1  | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Code failure above happens here

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import psutil
import threading
import time
import traceback

# Import your application modules
from database.database_config import get_db
from database.models import *
from database.crud import *
from api.interview import complete_interview
from api.chat_handling import *
from api.user_registration import register_user
from api.stripe import *
from services.utils import *
from config.env_var import *

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        # Check database connectivity
        db.execute('SELECT 1')
        db_status = "Connected"

        # Memory and Thread Count
        memory_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
        thread_count = threading.active_count()

        response_time = time.time() - start_time
        logger.info(f"Health check passed in {response_time:.2f} seconds, Memory Usage: {memory_usage}%, Thread Count: {thread_count}, DB Status: {db_status}")
        return {"message": "Hello, World!"}

    except Exception as e:
        response_time = time.time() - start_time
        logger.error(f"Health check failed in {response_time:.2f} seconds: {e}")
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

For reference, here's how I define my dependency injection:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from services.utils import logger
import traceback
from config.env_var import *

DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

Base = declarative_base()
db_url = f'postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:5432/{DB_NAME}'

try:
    engine = create_engine(db_url)
except Exception as e:
    logger.info(f"Error creating database engine: {e}")
    logger.info(traceback.format_exc())
    raise

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(f"Database session error: {e}")
        logger.info(traceback.format_exc())
        raise
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I am able to successfully connect via my FastAPI Docker instance to my PostgreSQL instance via this script though:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import os

DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

db_url = f'postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:5432/{DB_NAME}'
engine = create_engine(db_url)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def test_session_local():
    session = SessionLocal()
    print(f"Session: {session}")
    session.close()

def test_db_connection():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        # Perform a simple query
        result = db.execute('SELECT 1')
        for row in result:
            print(row)
        db.close()
        print("Connection successful.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Connection failed: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_session_local()
    test_db_connection()
```

I don't see where I made a critical failure.

Comment: What the code that's _actually failing_ instead of the code that's working?

Comment: I made the edit.

Comment: Since you're importing _a lot_ as `from x import *`, is there any `get_db` functions _defined somewhere else in your project_? They would overwrite the `get_db` function you think you're calling in that case. It'd also recommend not swallowing exceptions when trying to debug, set a debug breakpoint inside your `get_db` function to verify that you're actually calling it, etc.

Comment: @MatsLindh you are right in your assumption. There was another endpoint I changed and I overwrote my original `get_db` method with the new one. Thanks!

Comment: Great! `import *`  is generally discouraged for that exact reason, and for a future where you suddenly define a variable in one of the other modules that uses the same name as something in the module that's importing. It's better to be explicit about which symbols you want to import.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a suggestion @MatsLindh I realized the error came from *another endpoint*

It's definition was:

```
import stripe
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from fastapi import Request, Depends, HTTPException
from typing import Callable, Dict

from config.env_var import STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
from database.crud import get_user_by_email, update_user_info
from database.enums import onboard_complete, two_chat, ten_chat, twenty_chat, monthly_subscription
from services.utils import logger

def stripe_api_client() -> stripe:
    return stripe

def get_db() -> Session:
    pass

async def extract_event(request: Request, stripe_api: stripe = Depends(stripe_api_client)):
    payload = await request.body()
    sig_header = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')
    try:
        return stripe_api.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.error(f"Invalid payload: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid payload")
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        logger.error(f"Invalid signature: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid signature")
```

Issue lies with this section, which passes effectively a `None Type` object, which overwrote my `get_db` from my `database_config.py`:

```
def get_db() -> Session:
    pass
```

So I removed that and imported my get_db and problem resolved!